# How to make if in array select db next row?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, logic

I need an array have 6 index ,
How to select row and check if not in an array push into?
if in array then select next row  till the array have 6 index

```
$data = array();

  for ($ii=0; $ii < 6; $ii++) { 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM article_category WHERE category_id = :category_id ORDER BY id DESC";
    $stmt = $connect_db_article->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':category_id', $category_id_array[$i]);
    $stmt->execute();
    $article_category_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if (!in_array($article_category_row['article_id'], $data)) {
      array_push($data, $article_category_row['article_id']);

    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand the question. Could you try to clarify "get newest row and check if in array select next continue to find not in array and push into array" a little?

Comment: Thanks for reply, I update the question, I tried to find a way push array till have 6 index, each time get one row and check isset in array or not, if not push into, if duplicate in array then back to select next row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just loop until sizeof($data)==6, something like;

```
$data = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM article_category WHERE category_id = :category_id ORDER BY id DESC";
$stmt = $connect_db_article->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':category_id', $category_id_array[$i]);
$stmt->execute();
while(sizeof($data) < 6 && $article_category_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  if (!in_array($article_category_row['article_id'], $data))
    array_push($data, $article_category_row['article_id']);
}
```

Comment: but how to let sql select next row?  this seems keep select same one

Comment: @user1775888 Hmm...? [$stmt->fetch()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) should always fetch the next row if one is available. Since it's called in a loop it should fetch all rows in order.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to re execute your query at each time, you will always have only one 'article_id' in your $data array.
Also you have to secure your code with try, catch()
You can try with this code :

```
$data = array();
$maxRow = 6;
$cpt = 0 ;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM article_category WHERE category_id = :category_id ORDER BY id DESC";
try {
    $stmt = $connect_db_article->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':category_id', $category_id_array[$i]);
    $stmt->execute();
    while($article_category_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) && $cpt < $maxRow) {
        if (!in_array($article_category_row['article_id'], $data)) {
            array_push($data, $article_category_row['article_id']);
            $cpt++;
        }
    }
}catch(PDOException $pdoException) {
    print $pdoException->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: but how to let sql select next row?  this seems keep select same one

Answer (score 0):

also you can delegate this treatment to your MySql Server with this sql query

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(article_id) FROM article_category WHERE category_id = :category_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6";
```

hope it help